# SSD seems to be causing a lock on folders and files in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, ssd

I recently switched from an HDD to a SSD in a Windows 7 environment. Since then I regularly experience files or folders being locked from renaming or deleting. The lock may take minutes or hours - I'm unsure about it.

It's not a system lock caused by a running application or anything alike. I'm aware that I cannot edit/delete a file/folder while it's in use anywhere else. And I'm experiencing this problem ever since I switched to the SSD, so I'm pretty sure it's related.

Does an SSD cause such lock outs - due to caching or anything? Is there a way to unlock such files manually?

System: Windows 7 Home 64 / Samsung SSD 840 EVO 250G / ASUS Notebook with i7 CPU

Comment: How do you know its not an application that is locking these files?

Comment: It's a totally different behavior than with the HDD. E.g. I can edit a simple batch text files (xy.bat) and save it. Then I run the batch file; the process ends and then I cannot edit the batch file again. That's weird, because the batch file itself is actually never blocked by the application it starts ... Lots of things like that.

Comment: That isn't normal behavior, something else, is going on

Comment: "Do SSD's cause this?" and answer is "No", and that's not a good question for here.  "It's not a system lock caused by a running application or anything alike." Prove it by showing us your research, or I just don't believe you.  :)  It's almost always a process locking the files, if not, then you have faulty hardware.

Comment: For now I'm closing it as a duplicate of "how do I determine what's locking my files?"; If you can prove it's not an application holding them open, and you've also determined it's not a faulty SSD, then you can edit that info into your question, and request to have it reopened.

Comment: I found a hint in another question on SO that may have fixed the issue:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4378192/windows-2008-r2-kernel-system-process-pid-4-is-locking-files-and-folders
Application Experience service needs to be enabled.

Comment: The question is not a duplicate. No handle that could be identified that locked the files in question. It was the Application Experience service, which does not show up as a handle. Also Unlocker was not able to detect any applications using the files. Enabling the mentioned service solved the issue.